# org-roam-capture; Problem with saving the file

Tags: org-mode

i try to use org-roam-capture with Firefox and Chrome on Linux Kubuntu 18.04 with Emacs 26.3.

here is my config:

```
(require 'org-roam)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r b") #'org-roam-switch-to-buffer)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r d") #'org-roam-dailies-date)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r f") #'org-roam-find-file)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r g") #'org-roam-graph-show)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c r i") #'org-roam-insert)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r r") #'org-roam)
(define-key org-roam-mode-map (kbd "C-c r t") #'org-roam-buffer-toggle-display)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C") 'org-roam-capture)

(setq org-roam-directory "/home/held/org-roam/")
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively org-roam-directory "\.org$"))
(setq org-roam-encrypt-files nil)
(setq org-roam-link-title-format "R:%s")
(setq org-roam-tag-sources '(prop all-directories))
(setq org-roam-tag-sort t)

(with-eval-after-load 'org-roam
  (with-eval-after-load 'company
    (with-eval-after-load 'org
      (require 'company-org-roam)
      (push 'company-org-roam company-backends)
      (require 'org-roam-protocol)
      )))

(org-roam-mode +1)
```

Here is the bookmarklet from Firefox (simple copied from documentation):

```
javascript:location.href = 'org-protocol://roam-ref?template=r&ref=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

The following is going wrong.

1. Starting the bookmarklet starts Emacs.
2. a buffer opens with name: "~/org-protocol:/roam-ref?template=r&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salz-helmreich.de%2Fkontakt&title=Online%20Kontaktformular"
3. usually the org-capture keys should be available : C-c C-c  or C-c C-k

but nothing...

4. If i save the buffer with C-x C-s the following message pops up:
   Directory ‘/home/held/org-protocol:/’ does not exist; create? (y or n)

Very strange.

It should save inside org-roam directory, right?

What is going wrong?

Comment: Hi, could you format your post to make it more readable please? Like putting code inside  `backquotes`, using bullet points, and trying to be as brief (use minimal working example) as possible?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be specific to org-roam-capture, what version of emacs are you using?

Comment: Hello,   im using Version 26.3 on Kubuntu 20.

Comment: Could you please tell me why do you think it is not org-roam-capture related? How could i check my capture configuration from start to end?

Comment: That's because I had the same problem with org-protocol (from browser or terminal too). And it looks like mr. Zamansky had it working https://cestlaz.github.io/post/using-emacs-70-org-protocol/